# ANR issue occur when native module is called in react native

Tags: android, react-native

> I created a native module and using it in react native app but it
> causes ANR. Error log is given below.

```
    Signal Catcher (runnable):tid=4 systid=20855 
#00 pc 0x29cb7d libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool) + 64)
#01 pc 0x4b4147 libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const + 134)
#02 pc 0x1f2e6b libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const + 34)
#03 pc 0x4bad89 libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*) + 240)
#04 pc 0x1a8c09 libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*) + 952)
#05 pc 0x49f5db libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool) + 390)
#06 pc 0x49e1e1 libart.so (art::ThreadList::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) + 288)
#07 pc 0x49db55 libart.so (art::Runtime::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) + 132)
#08 pc 0x270aa3 libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::HandleSigQuit() + 298)
#09 pc 0x27002b libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*) + 182)
#10 pc 0xafc5f libc.so (__pthread_start(void*) + 40)
#11 pc 0x65ef1 libc.so (__start_thread + 30)

main (native):tid=1 systid=20846 
#00 pc 0x5ffdc libc.so (syscall + 28)
#01 pc 0x20ca11 libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*) + 88)
#02 pc 0x1e5023 libart.so (art::GoToRunnable(art::Thread*) (.llvm.817763754809290887) + 226)
#03 pc 0x502f45 libart.so (art::JniMethodEnd(unsigned int, art::Thread*) + 8)
       at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:884)
       at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:182)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:109)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:69)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:121)
       at customsdk.android.sdk.SDK.ApiCalls.VolleySingleton$requestQueue$2.invoke(VolleySingleton.kt:22)
       at customsdk.android.sdk.SDK.ApiCalls.VolleySingleton$requestQueue$2.invoke(VolleySingleton.kt:19)
       at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
       at customsdk.android.sdk.SDK.ApiCalls.VolleySingleton.getRequestQueue(VolleySingleton.kt:19)
       at customsdk.android.sdk.SDK.ApiCalls.VolleySingleton.addToRequestQueue(VolleySingleton.kt:25)
       at customsdk.android.sdk.SDK.ApiCalls.ApiCalls.allAPIsCall(ApiCalls.kt:44)
       at customsdk.android.sdk.SDK.MyCustomSDK$Companion.initialise(MyCustomSDK.kt:69)
       at com.mventus.selfcare.activity.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:127)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7506)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:310)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2281)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)

perfetto_hprof_listener (native):tid=7 systid=20857 
#00 pc 0x9fbf4 libc.so (read + 8)
#01 pc 0x101ed libperfetto_hprof.so (void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, ArtPlugin_Initialize::$_33> >(void*) + 208)
#02 pc 0xafc5f libc.so (__pthread_start(void*) + 40)
#03 pc 0x65ef1 libc.so (__start_thread + 30)

Jit thread pool worker thread 0 (native):tid=8 systid=20858 
#00 pc 0x5ffdc libc.so (syscall + 28)
#01 pc 0x20ca11 libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*) + 88)
#02 pc 0x4bb635 libart.so (art::ThreadPool::GetTask(art::Thread*) + 80)
#03 pc 0x4bb509 libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run() + 68)
#04 pc 0x4bb44d libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*) + 104)
#05 pc 0xafc5f libc.so (__pthread_start(void*) + 40)
#06 pc 0x65ef1 libc.so (__start_thread + 30)

HeapTaskDaemon (waiting):tid=9 systid=20862 
#00 pc 0x5ffdc libc.so (syscall + 28)
#01 pc 0x20ca11 libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*) + 88)
#02 pc 0x239109 libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::GetTask(art::Thread*) + 432)
#03 pc 0x238f09 libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*) + 32)
       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(VMRuntime.java)
       at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:531)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)

ReferenceQueueDaemon (waiting):tid=10 systid=20864 
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
       at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:217)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)

FinalizerDaemon (waiting):tid=11 systid=20867 
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:190)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:211)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:273)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

Please help me in finding reason of ANR. I am suspecting volley. Thank you in advance.